# Using an external library (lightbox) with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS, and I want to add a lightbox for showing images. My lightbox code works like this (I am using [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)):

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" rel="shadowbox">image name</a>
```

But when I want to use the shadowbox with AngularJS like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="pic in pics" href="{{pic}}" rel="shadowbox">image name</a>
```

the shadowbox will be ignored, and it works like a normal link.
What is the best way to make this work?

I may have to write a directive, but I'm not familiar with it...

Comment: Please post a fiddle/plunk.

Comment: what is a fiddle/plunk??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net / http://plnkr.co

Comment: I can't do that... how would I add external libs to jsfiddle?? I would have to write my app from scratch again to make it work there! 
thanx anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that shadowbox processes the DOM only once and will not register AngularJS' DOM modifications.

The normal way is to write a wrapper directive which instantiates Shadowbox. I suggest you to call Shadowbox directly instead of using the auto-setup with the `rel="shadowbox"` attribute. Basically there are two steps:

1. Setup a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for Shadowbox
2. Register a function in the directive's scope that will be called when clicking on the link. Read the [Shadowbox documentation](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html) and [API documentation](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/api.html) on how to do that.

Directive prototype:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName') // you can use your own name here
.directive('shadowbox', function() {
  return {
    // here you can style the link/thumbnail/etc.
    template: '<a ng-click="openShadowbox()">{{imageName}}</a>',
    scope: {
      imageName: '@name',
      imageUrl: '@url'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      // the function that is called from the template:
      scope.openShadowbox = function () {

        // see Shadowbox documentation on what to write here.
        // Example from the documentation:

        Shadowbox.open({
          content:    '<div id="welcome-msg">Welcome to my website!</div>',
          player:     "html",
          title:      "Welcome",
          height:     350,
          width:      350
        });
      };

    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<a shadowbox name="image name" url="image url"></a>
```

Comment: thanks so much... I think this is the right way. Sadly, it won't work.
I tried showing an alert('test'); in the link function, and it does not get called :S

And the <a ng-click="openShadowbox()">{{name}}</a> shows literally "{{name}}" in the browser!

Comment: This is just a prototype of a directive that shows you how to access the Shadowbox object inside it. You have to make some modifications to it, depending on your needs :)

Comment: I know, but somehow I am not getting it to work :S thank you anyways!

Comment: Ah, replace the `=` in the scope by an `@`, and `name` in the template by `imageName` sorry :)

Comment: the function gets called now!! but somehow the {{name}} in the template does not get binded.. any idea why?

Comment: Should be {{imageName}}, I confused the attribute and scope variable's names

Answer (score -1):

Here are two Scenarios :

In first one  you are creating the html first and then you make plugin call, Hence it works fine.

But in second case, you are creating elements at runtime but your plugin call already fires.

Hence you need to make the plugin call, once all elements get created.

Hope this may be the solution for your case. :)

Comment: I understand, but the question is how to do that!
the shadowbox libs requires a Shadowbox.init(); call. I think this call is done before angularJS has finished injecting the DOM. How can I make this call only after angularjs is ready?